# How to disable tilemap in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've got a local ELK and I think that the tilemap bugs the 'Discovery' and 'Dashboard' pages loading if the Internet connection is unstable.

Kibana requests `https://tiles.elastic.co/v2/manifest?my_app_version=5.3.2`.

There is an option `tilemap.url` to change the URL, but is there a way to completely disable that function?

Comment: well you could edit the /etc/hosts in the kibana server and add `127.0.0.1 tiles.elastic.co` so the url will always resolve to localhost and never leave the server

Comment: @ugosan, it's the client who requests tiles.elastic.co, not the server.

Comment: in this case you could try to change `tilemap.url` to `127.0.0.1` so the client will never request tiles.elastic.co